# how to state a If to verify if a class has a specific attributte?

Tags: c#, css, selenium, if-statement, automation

I gotta verify if a button is "selected", if it is, then we can procede the test, if not, select it.

I tried the bellow code. What is the proper way to set up this?

External HTML:
I need to verify the class: see if it has the string "selected", if this div is selected then continue, if not, click on it to be "Selected".

```
<div class="list-toggle uppercase management_item newFeature selected" ng-class="{ 'selected': viewModel.selectedActionGroup == 'DistributionGroup', 'newFeature': i.isNew, 'standardFeature': !i.isNew}">
```

Code:

```
 var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".col-md-3 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)"));

            if (element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("selected"))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                element.Click();
            }
```

Also I tried this:

```
if (element.GetAttribute("class").("selected", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
            {
                element.Click();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
```

PD: If I hover over the "Else" statement it says is redundant, why is this?

The issue is that i made the verification but the program clicks on it either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change the locator by `xpath` :

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'list-toggle uppercase management_item newFeature')]"));

if (element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("selected"))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                element.Click();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check value of any attribute of element like this

```
element.GetAttribute("ng-class").Contains("selected");
```

Or you may simple run search by this condition

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//div[contains(@ng-class,'selected')]");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the way that this IF is build, it is logically correct?

Comment: If you want click if condition is true then you must put click in first place, and return in else.
or put ! in condition.

Comment: can you give me the example of where should I put it?

Comment: if (element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("selected"))
element.Click();
else return;

Comment: I think you misread the question, I need to click only it if the value "Selected" is NOT present

Comment: Ah sorry then u are correct in logic.
Though. you have "selected" both in class and in ng-class. You check class but you say that you need to check ng-class. Thats confusing

Comment: Fixed logic on the question, thanks for the feedback. Let's see why is not working how i want

Comment: Also, why u use "return"? It needed to get out of function. If your check is not in function then you dont need to return you need to do like 
if (!(element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("selected"))) element.Click(); and no else